# KML custom icons sometimes not show up

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been working a long time with KMLs on Google Maps and I've several applications drawing static and dynamic (generate by a PHP service upon a Postgis database) KMLS.

Everything works fine and the result is amazing but sometimes custom icons are drawn with the blue drop default icon instead.

I think this is a network issue. I've checked with two clients (in differents networks) in one of them the custom icons are showed up fine whereas in the other one not. Furthermore the custom icons sometimes appears for certain zoom values.

It happens from the begining, I don't change nothing on the application and suddenly everything works fine.

Should I embed the icon's images in KMLs? Does it solve the problem?

You can see an screenshot of this issue with only one layer active:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15451865/kmlrenderissue.png

When I was doing this screenshot, suddenly the problem disappear and every icons looks fine...

Here is on app where this issue happens http://mapadesevilla.geographica.gs

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to the `status_changed` event on your `KmlLayer` and outputing the result of the `getStatus()` method. This may give you some indication of what the issue is.

However, it looks like other people have had similar problems: http://www.alexstanhope.com/blog/technology/203/google-maps-tile-display-bug-kml-layers

Answer (score 0):

What format is your data in at the moment? 
There is a problem in the Google Maps API with displaying more than about 25 kml files 
(see http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2384) so I wouldn't recommend using kml/kmz.

Comment: This app use KML but the same issue happens with KMZ (see http://mirador.dipusevilla.es). I've just checked this issue only with one kmz and nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real example of the issue(it has been taken from mapadesevilla.geographica.gs), the icon of a point changes when the zoom goes down:

- Zoom 13 (Point A and Point B show up the custom icon):

[image: issue at zoom 13]

- Zoom 14 (Point A - custom icon, Point B is an hybrid)

[image: issue at zoom 14]

- Zoom 15 (Point A - default icon, Point B custom icon)

[image: issue at zoom 15]